# get undefined when fill input select html with thymeleaf Object in javascript

Tags: javascript, java, html, object, thymeleaf

I am trying to fill input value & text on option select in javascript. The data is get from thymeleaf in html.

here is my source model that i want to store in javascript.

```
public class JobClassEntity {

  private String jobClassId;
  private String jobTypeId;
  private String jobClassName;

  public JobClassEntity(String jobClassId, String jobTypeId, String jobClassName) {
    this.jobClassId = jobClassId;
    this.jobTypeId = jobTypeId;
    this.jobClassName = jobClassName;
  }
 
  //getter & setter
}
```

here is my source on controller.

```
   @GetMapping("/")
   public ModelAndView showCreateNewTml(ModelAndView m, Principal principal){

    User user = (User) ((Authentication) principal).getPrincipal();

    List<JobClassEntity> listJob = jobClassRepository.findAllAssetClass();
    m.addObject("jobclass", listJob);
    m.setViewName("timelines/create-new-timeline");

    return m;
}
```

listJob is contain 4 data (length listJob = 4). here is my part code page (test.html) where data from controller pass to .js

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
<![CDATA[*/

    var listJobC = /*[[${jobclass}]]*/ 'default';

>*/
</script>
```

after it pass to javascript (test.js). i try to fill the data to select option input.
here is my source .js.

```
for(jobc in listJobC)
    {
       var opt = document.createElement("option");
       opt.value= jobc.jobClassId;
       opt.innerHTML = jobc.jobClassName;

       seljob.appendChild(opt);
    }
```

after i run and test it, the select is show but the value & text is filled with **undefined**. This is the display of the [option value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUZXh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think `for(jobc in listJobC)` [is doing what you think it is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).  When I tested that code, it just returned the numbers `0` and `1` which don't have the properties you're looking for...  Either use `.forEach` or a regular `for` loop.

```
for (let i = 0; i < listJobC.length; i++) {
  jobc = listJobC[i];
  
  var opt = document.createElement("option");
  opt.value= jobc['jobClassId'];
  opt.innerHTML = jobc['jobClassName'];
  seljob.appendChild(opt);
}
```

Comment: Oh i think the mean for (x in Lobj) is iterate object x in list Lobj. Thank you for your help. it work on the page..